# IFstatement in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I want to write something like this :

```
<?php
$comment = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `communication` WHERE `ID`='$index' order by `Date_add` desc");
echo "<div class=\"row\">";
while ($com = mysql_fetch_assoc($comment)) {
    $side = mysql_query("SELECT Type FROM `client` WHERE `ID`='$comtype'");

      if ($side[0]==2) {
       echo "<div class=\"left\">";     // and i want to execute this line only when the next value of $side is equal to 1 or 9                          
       echo "<div class=\"inside1\">"
        ...
       echo "</div>";
       echo "</div>";                   // same as above, close div only, when the next value of $side is equal to 1 or 9
      } else if ($side[0]==1 || $side[0]==9) {
       echo  "<div class=\"right\">";           // Same here i want to execute this line only when the next value of $side is equal to 2    
       echo "<div class=\"inside2\">";
        ...
       echo "</div>";
       echo "</div>";                 // same as above, close div only, when the next value of $side is equal to 2
  }
}
echo "</div>";
```

I need to execute whole code, but i have div inside div, and i want  and  execute when value of $side[0] is different. For example:

```
Loop step 1:
$side[0]=2
so i want to execute: <div class=left> and everything in this div.
Loop step 2:
$side[0]=2 again
so i want to execute all in <div class=left> but i dont want to create another <div class=left>
Lopp step 3:
$side[0]=1
so previously $side[0] was equal 2, so now i want to create <div class=left> and everything in this div
Lopp step 4:
$side[0]=1 again
so i want to execute all in <div class=right> but i dont want to create another <div class=right>
    etc...
```

Anyone know how to achive effect like this ? Thanks for help in advice.

Comment: you should look into mysqli_ functions or PDO since mysql_ functions are going to be deprecated. Also your problem is more a PHP if problem, not a MYSQL IF

Answer (score 0):

Understanding your problem, you have two main din inside your while loop and inside those div you want to display result according to a particular column value. The way I can suggest you make to separate array based on the value from query. Then iterate through individual array and display it on the let/right div accordingly.